# Do other ORMs have code-first and db-first approaches too?

Tags: mysql, oracle, postgresql, orm

I am a `.NET developer`. A friend of mine asked on how to start coding in `PHP/MySQL`. I wanted to find him a list of starting links, so I searched for a couple of major concepts in PHP/MySQL.

However, I can't find anything related to code-first vs. db-first for PHP ORMs.

This made me skeptic about the generality of these concepts. Do other `ORMs` have these approaches?

Comment: The only time I heard those specific terms was from people in the .NET world.  "DB-first" is usually called "reverse-engineering" by other ORMs.

Comment: Reading the initial introductory and setting/configuration related documentation of php DB libraries will make it clear